# Listbox text Indent in Userform Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, text-indent

[**Update: Screenshot provided**]

How to remove the text indent for a listbox in excel userform?
I've been trying to find a solution for this for a long time now and I could not find any help online or offline.

I could do this for a textbox but setting `SelectionMargin` property to `False`. But I couldn't find this for a listbox. I tried to attach a screenshot but I do not have 10 reputation yet. :(

Screenshot:

[image: TextBox & ListBox]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `I tried to attach a screenshot but I do not have 10 reputation yet. :(` Now you have :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Yes, I do now. :) I wanted to attach a screenshot of what I really meant, for more clarity.

Comment: Ah! No... I am not aware if this is possible. However let me check if any api's can do this...